# c++ Constructor behavior

Tags: c++, constructor

i'm newbie in c++ languge, and i'm fimiliar with java language.

in Java world, the code looks ok , but not in c++.

can someone please explain why the both constructors are called?

```
class Position {

  public:

    Position(void) 
    {
        std::cout<<"defualt constructor\n";
    }

    Position(unsigned int row,unsigned int col) 
    {
        std::cout<<"two Arguments constructor\n";
        row_index = row;
        col_index = col;
    }

private:
    unsigned int row_index;
    unsigned int col_index;
  };

class Tool
 {
public:
    Tool(char Team,unsigned int row,unsigned int col)
    {
        pos = Position(row,col);
        team = Team;
    }
    std::string To_string()
    {
        std::string str = "team: ";
        str+= team; 
        str+= " pos: ";
        str+= pos.To_string();  
        return str;
    }
    char Get_team()
    {
        return team;
    }
private:
    Position  pos;
    char team; // A or B

};

int main(void)
{
 Tool t = Tool('A',1,3);
 return 0;
}
```

i intended to call for the two arguments constructor

OUTPUT:

defualt constructor

two Arguments constructor

Comment: The code *is* ok in C++.  The issue is that you're using Java as a model in understanding and writing C++ code.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Tool` class the `Position` object is first default constructed before the execution of the `Tool` constructor body is executed. Then you create a new temporary `Position` object in the `Tool` constructor body, and use it to *assign* to `pos`.

The important part here is that object construction is a three-step process:

1. The object is allocated
2. The object is initialized and all its members are constructed (here the `Position` default constructor is called)
3. The constructor of the object is executed (here the two-argument `Position` constructor is called)

To only use the two-argument `Position` constructor, and not simply assign to the `pos` object, you need to use an *constructor initializer list*. You do this by modifying the `Tool` constructor as this:

```
Tool(char Team,unsigned int row,unsigned int col)
    : pos(row, col),  // Initializes the `pos` object
      team(Team)      // Initialize the `team` member
{
    // No code needed, the members have already been initialized
}
```

Comment: let assume that 'Tool' hold array of 'Possition' instead of one object, and every Position is bigger by 1, how can it be done with the format of NAMEOFCLASS(arguments...) : assign(){}

Comment: @dids If all elements are to be initialized to the same "value" then I suggest you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, it has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which takes the number of elements and the default value for all elements. If you want different values, then you simply can't do it, you have to loop over the array in the body of the constructor and assign each and every element.

Comment: consider all the elements have diffrent value, if  i work with methood you mention, then the both constructor ( defualt constructor two Arguments constructor) will be called for every element, right? is it efficent? it's look like a duplicate call.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, all member variables are constructed before the body of the constructor is entered. Your code default automatically constructs a Position, and then in the body of the constructor creates *another* Position and *assigns* it to the previously constructed one.

You need to pass the parameters of Position using an initialisation list:

```
  Tool(char Team,unsigned int row,unsigned int col) : pos( row, col ), team(Team) {
    // constructor now empty
  }
```

In general, the body of a constructor should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

When the execution enters constructor body, member objects, of the owning class, need to be constructed (default constructor is used, if no explicit call to constructor is specified).

Upon entering the constructor body, `Position(row,col)` in `pos = Position(row,col);` creates a temporary `Position` object, which gets assigned to `pos`.

If you want to avoid calling default constructor, of member objects, in such a case, use initialize members in an initializer-list:

```
Tool(char Team,unsigned int row,unsigned int col)
: pos (row, col), team (Team)
    {
    }
```

Why the code, in Java, works, as you expect, is due to the fact, that you, always, operate on *references* to objects, rather than on objects, as values. And non-initialized member object *references* in Java, would be default initialized to `null` (if memory serves right), until you create an object, and assign a *reference* to it, to a member variable.